UserForm 1 run comand button is affecting UserForm 2 combo boxes
I am looking for some help,I have created two user forms and inside there are several combo boxes to handle some Excel data.
First user from is to input the data into the sheet and second is to select this data on the sheet and edit accordingly.
The code seemed to work until suddenly started to have issues.
Once I run the sub routine for the first user form as I press the command button to accept this changes, and  as I debug I can see the code goes also over some of the other combo boxes change event that are not linked to the first user from but linked to the second user form.
I am struggling to understand why this is happening. Any ideas please?
I have tried to change the combo boxes names so I though this might have been the reason, but this still does not seem to work. I will try to create a new command button see if this works, but something does not make sense I would though the code for each userform does not interfere with the code of another userform, or does it? I do ocasionaly VBA codding but I am not super experienced so hopping for some help here.
